# Need JQuery colour picker that supported Jquery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I tried to find on google but that is not supported to the 1.3.2 I need Jquery colour picker that supported to the Jquery 1.3.2

If anybody can provide colour picker that can supported to the 1.3.2

Thanks

Comment: Hi Florija not yet I need Jquery 1.3.2 supported spectrum is good but that is not supported to 1.3.2

Comment: Edited my answer, see the new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some color pickers:

- http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/
- http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/
- http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker
- http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/ **< This one looks nice**
- http://www.digitalmagicpro.com/jPicker/

*Edit:* Here is a color picker that should work with 1.3.2: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/